# How To Check If CustomSetting OrgDefault is empty?

Tags: customsetting

Documentation [Custom Settings Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) says:

> getOrgDefaults():
>
> If no custom setting data is defined for the organization, this method
>   returns an empty custom setting object.

How to check if it is empty, because == null is not working here.

```
    XyCustomSettings__c customSettingObject = XyCustomSettings__c.getOrgDefaults():
    Boolean checkboxSet = (customSettingObject == null)?true:customSettingObject.checkbox_Activated__c;
```

I also tried

```
if (customSettingObject.checkbox_Activated__c == null)
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For hierarchy settings, you can use:

```
Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().Id == null
```

If there was no data, there would be a null ID value; otherwise you would have a non-null ID value.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the custom setting values
  if custom setting  name is customse__c

```
Map<String,customse__c> customsetMap = customse__c.getAll();
```

check the map empety or not by using isEmepty method

```
if(customsetMap.isEmpty())
```

returns true or false

another way is

```
list<customse__c> customList = customse__c.getAll().Values();
If(customList.size()==0)
```

to check the size

Comment: I'm trying to check the Org Defaults, not all settings..